# Fresh 20.04.4 Install Won't Boot

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, system-installation, amd-graphics

I can't seem to get my fresh Ubuntu 20.04.4 install to boot up. I have gotten the Windows 10 install usb stick to boot, and install windows, and I've booted up a fresh install of Win 10. I've gotten an Arch install .iso to boot up via usb, and the Ubuntu-Server 20.04.3 install .iso to boot up via usb, and the Ubuntu-Desktop 20.04.4 install .iso to boot up, **but only in safe graphics mode**, via usb. I have read that there may be some problems with native graphics support for my video card, and separately, that there may be some graphics conflict caused by my WRX80 motherboard's firmware. So far, the only Linux GUI that I've been able to boot has been the Ubuntu-Desktop install .iso, in safe graphics mode, via usb. It seems that Windows automatically boots in some kind of safe graphics mode.

I would think that my problem is graphics related, but my Ubuntu installs don't even make it to the GRUB bootloading screen. Something is happening that prevents GRUB from loading or displaying, all I get is the Supermicro splash screen forever (I've let it go for half an hour). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks, I'd be glad to supply any boot logs or config files or whatever. My motherboard is running the latest firmware, 1.0c.

I believe I am having the exact problem described in the Level1Techs Youtube video titled "Threadripper Pro: First Look at the ASUS Pro WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI + 32 Core TR Pro 3975WX" at time 2:48: https://youtu.be/G1yiOgtE7D4?t=168. If I had an ASUS motherboard instead of a Supermicro motherboard, I would know exactly what to do, and I would probably have a working linux install right now. Alas, I have the Stupourmicro board, and I can't boot into GRUB. I have set my motherboard's firmware to prefer offboard VGA. Below is a copy of a post I made on Ask Ubuntu about this same problem.

Here is my hardware:

- Corsair AXi Series, AX1600i PSU
- Supermicro M12SWA-TF Motherboard
- AMD Ryzen Threadripper Pro 3975WX
- Supermicro (Samsung) 64GB 288-Pin DDR4 3200 (PC4-25600) Server Memory (MEM-DR464MC-ER32)
- MSI Mech Radeon RX6700 XT 12GB
- LSI Broadcom SAS 9300-8i 8-port 12Gb/s HBA
- 12 of Seagate Exos X18 18TB Enterprise HDD
- 3 of Team Group T-FORCE CARDEA Z44L M.2 2280 1TB PCIe Gen4 x4, NVMe 1.4